# C# Dynamics CRM Online “The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.”

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, office365, crm, dynamics-crm-online

This is an example of web request  from CodeActivity on Dynamics CRM Online .

```
 public class CodeActivity1 : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {

        var postUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        var result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        webresponse.Close();
        .....

    }
...
}
```

I receive "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." error. From the Microsoft documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx) are the following limitations:

- Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
- Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
- IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
- Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving those credentials.

Do you have suggestions or ideas relating to the nature of the problem ??

Comment: This type of error in CRM generally indicates an issue with the authentication.  Are you sure you don't need to pass any authentication information along with your request?

Comment: @Nathan The service https://httpbin.org/get is public and not require authentication

Answer (score 0):

It could be that something in your environment is changing server cert on the fly. Many sniffing app can do it (for example Fiddler). In other words make sure that certificate that you get from httpbin.org is correct. You can check if problem is in validating server certificate by adding validation handler that will ignore any cert error at the beginning of you code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.If I insert the code you've shown I get the following error:System.Security.SecurityException: 
 Request for the permission of type
 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=b7aa5c561934e089' failed. at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context) at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ProxyCustomActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)

Comment: Ok, in sandbox isolation mode HTTP and HTTPS are allowed so one thing that I can think of is that this server certificate cannot be validated. Could you check if you can access to for example https://msdn.microsoft.com from your plugin?

Comment: It could be a problem on the certificates 
This is ok  "https://httpbin.org/get"
This is ko  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
What are the differences?

Comment: Could you check what is the value of ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue and ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol attributes in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I Rewrite the correct scriptin the hope that it can be useful to someone.
Thanks to @pen for suggestions

```
public class CodeActivity1 : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            ITracingService tracingService = context.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            var postUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;

            HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

            var result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            webresponse.Close();
            .....
    }
...
}
```

Comment: TLS 1.2 - companies have been warning people for over a year that they'll turn anything less than TLS1.1 off. GDSs like Sabre and Amadeus switched to TLS1.2 on December 2015. You could have used `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` alone. Also note that this won't work unless you have .NET 4.5.2 installed.

Comment: Why don't you use HttpClient anyway?

Comment: @Panagiotis: Kanavos  Why do you advice me to use HttpClient? 
My requirement is to test a rest https

Comment: And HttpClient was createt to simplify calling REST APIs, eg `var client=new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var json=await client.GetStringAsync(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");` will return a json string. You can use `Get`, `Post`, `Put`, `Delete` methods, all of them asynchronous. You can control the content, check the response status befor reading the response content etc.